# python import * from subdirectory not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a structure like this:

```
main_folder
├── main.py
├── folder1
    ├── function1.py
    └── function2.py
    └── ...
    └── function20.py
```

and I want to import all the files from folder1 into main.py

It does not work when i write `from folder1 import *`, but it works when I specifically write `from folder1 import function1`. Considering I have many scripts under `folder1`, I would prefer to have them all imported without type each name out. Is there any way to do this (like `import *`)?

Comment: ``from X import *`` only imports names global to ``X``. A submodule ``X.Y`` isn't actually added to ``X`` until imported, and ``from X import *`` won't import submodules.

Comment: what is the right way to import all of them? @MisterMiyagi

Comment: I would say "write them all out", but the question seems to exclude that.

Comment: You could include an `__all__ = ['function1', 'function2', ..., 'function20']` in your `__init__.py` in `folder1` but you still would have to "write them all out" at least once.

Comment: There is some really hacky stuff you could do like walk through your subdirectory in your `__init__.py`, appending everything to `__all__` that meets the criteria of a submodule but I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

List all python (.py) files in the current folder and put them as `__all__` variable in `__init__.py`

```py
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

Importing * is not a good idea for several reasons, including name clashes and making it hard to analyze the code.

Comment: Heads up that this won't work if the package is stored inside a zip file or any other structure not on the filesystem. This might need ``importlib`` to do correctly.